# ViewPager loads deleted image instead of the one selected from the Galerry

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, bundle

I have made a sample project with `ViewPager`. It picks a new image from the Gallery, created a new page and then displays the image. It works well **until I delete some page**. After that, when I pick a new image from the Gallery, the app creates a new page, **BUT the previous image is loaded**

Image Uris are passed via `Bundle` and somehow the previous bundle object is being passed instead of the proper Uri.

**Explanation:**

Line 95 is where I create a new `Fragment` and pass it a `Uri Parcelable`

Line 110 is where I get the `Uri` and pass it to `Picasso` to load it.

Line 26 is where I delete the Page and refresh `ViewPager`

Any ideas why previous image is loaded instead of the one I pick?

Comment: It seems that you're not deleting the pages from the `List<PlaceholderFragment> pages` inside your adapter, but only in `List<PlaceholderFragment> mPages` of your Activity

Comment: @NicolasSimon The same effect if I recreate the `Adapter`. Please check http://paste.ofcode.org/AjZuJdCexX87keWLaKiGbq (line 28). Line 27 is not needed.

Comment: Simply try adding a `public void deletePageAt(int position) { pages.remove(position); notifyDataSetChanged();} ` in your adapter, and call this instead. Furthermore, you should also have the same logic to add a new page, therefore not needing 2 references of your items, but only one, in your adapter

Comment: @NicolasSimon Tried that approach before and now again. The same happens. I create 2 pages and load 2 images. I then delete page 2 and load another image. But the image from the deleted page 2 gets loaded. Check it pls http://paste.ofcode.org/dXR5xyVspjwhF76s7dMCjm